# My WIFI is stoped after kernel update

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I was required to install WiFi driver manualy due to after standart installation my WiFi didn't work. So, manual installation did help but it gone after each kernel update and I need to install the driver again. Is anyway to add this driver into standart ubuntu distribution package or to avoid the erasure of my driver by kernel updates?

Comment: Where did you get the driver from and how was it installed?

Comment: The driver you've compiled (manual installation) is not erazed, but you need to recompile to make it work with a new kernel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support

Comment: @Jeremy31 the driver taken from here https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git